# Share audio file (.mp3) via Facebook, email, and SMS/MMS

Tags: android, facebook, audio, facebook-graph-api, share

I have an audio file (.mp3) and some information related to it. I want to share with Facebook, E-mail, SMS/MMS, etc..

What I have done is: when user clicks on the share button, it pops up list of all supported applications that can handle this Intent. But this does not show Facebook and SMS/MMS options.

Here is my code..

```
public void shareWithFriends(int resId)
{
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Ringtone File : "+ getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId)+".mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Ringtone File : "+getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId)+".mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.android.soundfiles/"+resId));
    share.putExtra("sms_body","Ringtone File : "+ getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId)+".mp3");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
}
```

Here are some results:

1. When I use MIME type `audio/mp3`, only the email options pops up. No Facebook and SMS/MMS share.
2. When I use MIME type `*/*`, Email and SMS options pops up. No Facebook option is there.

Here it is interesting to note that when I click on the SMS option, only text appears. I don't see any MP3 file attached (the same thing happens in *Whatsapp* (as I have *Whatsapp* installed on my phone). However, when I click on any mail application (for example, Gmail or Yahoo mail) it shows me the MP3 file attached.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 10):

There is no option for Facebook, but you can share email and MMS with Bluetooth. Here is my code. Take a look if it helps you:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+mypath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
break;
```

Here my path is the path of the sound file on the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital).

Comment: don't use fixed path..use getExternalStorageDirectory(); instead of "file:///"+mypath...

Comment: Uri.parse("file:/// is necessary for share intent.....yes getExternalStorageDirectory() can be used to get paths of file

Comment: My error is "file unknown file not sent" .I tried to send using bluletooth

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to share an mp3 over services that don't support it.

- Facebook supports text, pictures and videos.
- SMS is plain text (and only very short plain text)
- MMS does support audio, but (as far as I can tell from observation (i.e. without reading the spec)) only very low bit rate audio in some format that usually comes in a file with a .3g extension

The apps do not show up in the list of supported apps for mp3 because *they are not supported*.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. So final result would be like "i cannot share my audio file to Facebook."

Comment: Not using their standard interface. Going via an app might make it possible. It is probably worth investigating AudioBoo.

Comment: I see Whatsapp option, but when i select that app, it doesnot attach my audio file. What can be the reason for that. However when i select any mail app.(Gmail or YahooMail),i see the attached file and again i can see the mail is sent with necessary attachments.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("audio/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.fromFile(new File("filepath")));            
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File f=new File("full audio path");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+f.getAbsolutePath());
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try this.

```
 final Intent sendIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "bod of sms");
            sendIntent.setType("*/*");
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"test.amr");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
            Log.e("Path", "" + uri);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code its working for me to share audio via intent.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/abc.mp3";


        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + path));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```